# Unable to reindex flat category

Tags: category, indexing, flat

**Magento 1.8.x; Ultimo theme**

Didn't find anything for this probably popular problem.

After reindex categories on localhost I have this:

```
2015-04-29T11:20:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
Trace: #0 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2117): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#6 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(638): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#7 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1461): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#8 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1475): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#9 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(260): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#10 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#14 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#15 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/local.dev/www/host/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Here is SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_store_1` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'entity_id' ,
  `parent_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'parent_id' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'created_at' ,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'updated_at' ,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '' COMMENT 'path' ,
  `position` int NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'position' ,
  `level` int NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'level' ,
  `children_count` int NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'children_count' ,
  `store_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Store Id' ,
  `all_children` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'All Children' ,
  `available_sort_by` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Available Product Listing Sort by' ,
  `children` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Children' ,
  `custom_apply_to_products` int NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Apply To Products' ,
  `custom_design` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Custom Design' ,
  `custom_design_from` datetime NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Active From' ,
  `custom_design_to` datetime NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Active To' ,
  `custom_layout_update` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Custom Layout Update' ,
  `custom_use_parent_settings` int NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Use Parent Category Settings' ,
  `default_sort_by` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Default Product Listing Sort by' ,
  `description` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Description' ,
  `display_mode` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Display Mode' ,
  `filter_price_range` decimal(12,4) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Layered Navigation Price Step' ,
  `image` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Image' ,
  `include_in_menu` int NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Include in Navigation Menu' ,
  `is_active` int NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Is Active' ,
  `is_anchor` int NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Is Anchor' ,
  `landing_page` int NULL default NULL COMMENT 'CMS Block' ,
  `meta_description` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Meta Description' ,
  `meta_keywords` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Meta Keywords' ,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Page Title' ,
  `name` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
  `page_layout` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Page Layout' ,
  `path_in_store` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Path In Store' ,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Thumbnail Image' ,
  `umm_cat_block_bottom` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Block Bottom' ,
  `umm_cat_block_proportions` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Proportions: Subcategories / Block Right' ,
  `umm_cat_block_right` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Block Right' ,
  `umm_cat_block_top` text NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Block Top' ,
  `umm_cat_label` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Category Label' ,
  `url_key` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'URL Key' ,
  `url_path` varchar(255) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Url Path' ,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_PATH` (`path`),
  INDEX `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_LEVEL` (`level`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_FLAT_STORE_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Catalog Category Flat (Store 1)' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

As you understand, its also impossible to create such table manualy

[image]

I'm unable to change value of Catalog Category Flat. Even if try hardcode.

**upd.1**

On live in `system / configuration` flat category is `enabled`

**And on Live table is without foreign keys? Why magento decided to create them on localhost???**

In other words

both `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) and `core_store` (`store_id`) local magento indexer trying to create (on localhost). But on live server after reindex if I call `SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_category_flat_store_1` I don't see any foreign_keys

**upd.2**

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2015-04-29 16:05:28 7f7a3191b700 Error in foreign key constraint of table magento_host/catalog_category_flat_store_1:
FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ) COMMENT='Catalog Category Flat (Store 1)' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
(`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ) COMMENT='Catalog Category Flat (Store 1)' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

I tried to create table manually and replaced original SQL query with fields from tables

```
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  ...
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
```

instead of

```
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'entity_id' ,
  ...
  `store_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Store Id' ,
```

**upd.3**

I diff 2 files (file from custom magento and from default magento). `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat` has no any changes.

I tried to get

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->catalog_resource
```

and didn't find rewrite node there.

I looked at default magento tables and here what I have found:

Custom `core_store` also have no FOREIGN KEYs while native magento have them. Also native magento `catalog_category_flat_store_1` have

```
`entity_id` int(10)
`store_id` smallint(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the MySQL error code 1215, it looks like you have mismatching column definition in your flat table. When you establish a FK constraint, the columns must be identical.

Your FK `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` uses `core_store.store_id` as the reference. I checked CE 1.9, and it's supposed to be of `smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL`. However, I'm seeing your flat table is trying to create `store_id` with `smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default`, which gives you an error.

I'm not familiar with how the flat table gets created, but there's definitely something wrong with the column definitions. I suggest you check your `core_store.store_id` and make sure that is the same as what the flat table is trying to create.

**Update:**

If you're missing FKs on the flat table, it's not correct, as it's supposed to be there. You may have some customization that removed things incorrectly.

Check out `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::_getStaticColumns`, and see if you see `store_id` get `'type' => array(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, 5)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Field types are different. I tried to execute query with right field types. But it was unsuccessful. And another question: why magento tries to create table with foreing keys while live creates this table without them.

Comment: I wasn't clear what you meant by that in your original post. Which table's FKs are you referring to?

Comment: both `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) and `core_store` (`store_id`) local magento indexer trying to create (on localhost). But on live server after reindex if I call SHOW CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_store_1`  I don't see any foreign_keys

Comment: If I remove one of foreign_keys from query manualy - the query doesn't execute.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: added upd.3 section to my answer. Probably I forgot to say, that magento 1.8 I work with have installed Ultimo theme. My further question is what to do? Try to add foreign keys to core_store and check other tables? Try to compare and fix by some recovery tool? Which tool is better for use?  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool ?